# knockout conditional binding weird behavior

Tags: javascript, if-statement, knockout.js, conditional-statements, visible

I wanted to display missed call icon on getting a missed call , so for that i am maintaining a list of missed call received and i am comparing it with the current ID like shown below

```
<div class="col m1" data-bind="visible:$component.missedCallList().indexOf($data._id)>=0">
   <img src="${require(`./../../../../icons/icon-missed-call.svg`)}" alt="" class="responsive-img _badges">
 </div>
```

But the visibility isnt toggling when the list is updated or empty.

so on a certain event i am removing the entry like

```
removeFromList(index){
  if (index >= 0) {
            this.missedCallList().splice(index, 1)
        }
}
```

But it isnt updating on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `()` when you call `splice`. Instead call `splice` directly on the observable array.

e.g.

```
missedCallList.splice(index, 1)
```

Also in your code `this` might be referring to the remove function when it should probably be referring to the parent `missedCallList` property. You can set `this` to another variable in the parent scope and access that from within the function.

e.g.

```
var self = this;

function removeFromList(index) {
  if (index >= 0) {
    self.missedCallList.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'KnockoutBindingHandler' has no compatible call signatures.  **error**

Comment: i got it 
`private missedCallList: KnockoutObservableArray<any> = ko.observableArray();` has to be used i was using `private missedCallList: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable();
`